# Veto an Eclipse 4 view becoming invisible?

Tags: eclipse, e4

In our E4 RCP application we have a perspective that contains a view folder with a couple of E4 views (MParts).
One of these views is a CRUD view, ie. a view that allows for editing and saving a particular entity instance.

Whenever this view becomes dirty, i.e. the edited entity has been changed but is not saved yet, (for some internal reason) we want to block a change to another view in the same view folder (which would make the CRUD view invisible).
Is there a possibility in E4 to veto a view becoming invisible?

Of course we can register a part listener for the MPart in the EPartService, but that would only allow to receive a partHidden event, which is too late.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a reasonable way to do this.

The part stack is implemented in `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer` using a `CTabFolder`.

Although `CTabFolder` has a selection listener that lets you listen to the tab selections it does not provide a way to veto the selection. So even if you write a custom stack renderer extending the standard renderer you still can't control this.

You could write a completely new stack renderer that didn't use `CTabFolder` but this is a lot of work.